# Android how to find time execution of onCreate(), onClick() and other inbuilt methods etc using AspectJ

Tags: android, aspectj

I am using AspectJ and I need to know time taken by onCreate, onClick or any such inbuilt Android ActivityManager methods. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you use AspectJ only for measuring timing?

Comment: Not just timing but also to check the order of method execution.

Comment: I would check ordering just in test unless it is multithreading environment

Comment: For timing I would use https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

Comment: But this is complete off topic since it is not related to your question, sorry

Comment: I have found a way to measure time for onCreate like this - 
pointcut hi() : execution(* ActivityName.onCreate(..)) ; //This works
But I want to know how can I measure time taken by onClick to execute.

Comment: Is it not like change class name and method name in the call above?

Comment: It doesnt work for other built in methods like onClick. I just see it working for onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Here is a wonderful blog that explains how to achieve this http://ikrk.wz.cz/archiv/23-how-to-use-aspectj-with-android. It works :)